# Parse SubQuery Priority

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Say I have two queries in a compound query. Say the potential results exceed the query limit. How does Parse prioritize which query should fill up the result first?

Does it use the first query and fill up as much as possible then move onto the next query until it hits the limit?

```
PFQuery *lotsOfWins = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Player"];
[lotsOfWins whereKey:@"wins" greaterThan:@150];

PFQuery *fewWins = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Player"];
[fewWins whereKey:@"wins" lessThan:@5];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[fewWins,lotsOfWins]];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {

}];
```

So in this case if the table "Player" has 2000 entries and the query limit is 1000 which query has priority? "fewWins" or "lotsOfWins" ?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far in accordance with the help center's [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: As for as I know the query will be executed and from overall result the limit no of results are returned. Then pagination can be used and further results can be collected.
https://parse.com/questions/fetch-all-data-in-a-table-using-pfquery
Check this.